# How do I assign non-sequential values for the values and weights for `AVERAGE.WEIGHTED`?

Tags: google-sheets

I have values and weights that are all in separate columns and I want to use the `AVERAGE.WEIGHTED` function in Google Sheets. However, when I do something like: `=AVERAGE.WEIGHTED((D7, D11, D15, D19, D23), (P7, P11, P15, P19, P23))` then I get a formula parse error.

What is the correct syntax for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### AVERAGE.WEIGHTED function

- `=AVERAGE.WEIGHTED(values, weights, [additional values], [additional weights])`
- See Google Support: [AVERAGE.WEIGHTED function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9084098)

---

##### Formula Parse Error

Your formula `=AVERAGE.WEIGHTED((D7, D11, D15, D19, D23), (P7, P11, P15, P19, P23))` can't be parsed because

1. `"D7, D11, D15, D19, D23"` is not a **value**     (e.g. `95%` or `A3`)
   `"P7, P11, P15, P19, P23"` is not a **weight**  (e.g. `25%` or `B3`)
2. `"D7, D11, D15, D19, D23"` is not a **range**   (e.g. `D7:D23`)
   `"P7, P11, P15, P19, P23"` is not a **range**   (e.g. `P7:P23`)
3. `"D7, D11, D15, D19, D23"` is not an **array** of values (e.g. `{95%, 90%, 85%}` or `{A3, A5, A7}`
   `"P7, P11, P15, P19, P23"` is not an **array** of weights (e.g. `{25%, 10%, 15%}` or `{B3, B5, B7}`

Either of the following formulas would be valid:

1. `=AVERAGE.WEIGHTED(value1, weight1, value2, weight2, ..., ..., value(n), weight(n))`
   e.g. `=AVERAGE.WEIGHTED(D7, P7, D11, P11, D15, P15, D19, P19, D23, P23)`
2. `=AVERAGE.WEIGHTED({array_of_values}, {array_of_weights})`
   e.g. `=AVERAGE.WEIGHTED({D7, D11, D15, D19, D23}, {P7, P11, P15, P19, P23})` ***(columns)***
   e.g. `=AVERAGE.WEIGHTED({D7; D11; D15; D19; D23}, {P7; P11; P15; P19; P23})` ***(rows)***

##### Example with data

|  | A | B |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Value** | **Weight** |  | **Weighted Average** |
| **2** |  |  |  | `=AVERAGE.WEIGHTED({A3,A5,A7,A9,A11}, {B3,B5,B7,B9,B11})` |
| **3** | 95% | 25% |  | `=87.7%` |
| **4** |  |  |  |  |
| **5** | 90% | 10% |  |  |
| **6** |  |  |  |  |
| **7** | 85% | 15% |  |  |
| **8** |  |  |  |  |
| **9** | 88% | 20% |  |  |
| **10** |  |  |  |  |
| **11** | 82% | 30% |  |  |

Comment: Using curly braces in place of parentheses solved the issue, thanks. Is this just a syntax issue by Google Sheets? Why are curly braces considered values whereas parentheses are not?

Comment: Brackets are okay but the value inside the brackets could not be parsed: `=AVERAGE.WEIGHTED((D7), (P7), (D11), (P11), (D15), (P15), (D19), (P19), (D23), (P23))` would have worked just fine. `"D7, D11, D15, D19, D23"` could not be parsed as a value, a cell reference, a range, or an array. Curly braces are used in gSheets and MS Excel for arrays, whereas brackets are not. `{D7, D11, D15, D19, D23}` is a 5 col x 1 row array and `{D7; D11; D15; D19; D23}` is a 1 col x 5 row array.